# Autoplay em aúdio após consulta

Tags: jquery, áudio

Tenho um problema em meu sistema.
Acontece que eu tenho um script em jQuery que simplesmente, após uma consulta no banco, reproduz um aúdio no navegador.

```js
$('body').append('<embed src="audio/found.mp3" hidden="true" autostart="true" type="audio/mp3">');
```

Acontece que, se a guia não estiver focada no navegador, ou seja, se eu não estiver com a guia do site aberta, ou estiver em outro programa, o áudio não reproduz, e eu preciso que ele reproduza **sempre**, sem **exceções**.
O site já possui HTTPS (que eu pensei ser um limitador desta função), mas mesmo assim, não vai.
Existe alguma biblioteca que me ajude nisso e que garante que o áudio sempre será reproduzido?

Comment: pode ser uma política do browser, acontece em todos? por que está usando `<embed>` e não a tag `<audio>`.

Comment: Eu já tentei usar a audio e dava o mesmo erro. Aí mudei a tag mas mesma coisa..

Comment: Vc está usando setTimeout ou setInterval?

Comment: Não. O áudio é tocado logo após o sucess do ajax.

Comment: Vitor, conseguiu resolver ?

Answer (score -1):

não sei como você fez o código, mas fiz um teste aqui e funcionou normalmente, mesmo estando em outra aba:

```
<audio id="myaudio" controls style="display: none;">
    <source src="starwars.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<script>
  $.post({
  url : "teste.php",
  data : {
  f : "f"
  },
  success: function(msg){
  document.getElementById("myaudio").play();
  }
  });
<script>
```

OBS: por algum motivo se eu usar o seletor do Jquery "$" a função "play()" não é acionada.